# Both replication masters stop by themselves

Tags: mysql, replication

I did a master/master replication with MySQL on a Gentoo OVH Release 2, all work fine in my test phase. I put it in production, the replication works fine for 1 or 2 days, but this morning, I don't know why, my slave stops running!

So now the log position is bad. I can't just restart slave and my replication doesn't work.

I want a master/master replication to make a backup server with an IP failover, so only one server is writing/reading in the database at same time.

When I go to MySQL and click on `Show slave status`, I see an error like:

> Error 'Duplicate entry '411465' for key 1' on query. Default database .... etc.

Did this error stop my replication? If yes, why do I get this error? The second server does nothing on the database, so normally, there is no problem with the autoincrement, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The provided error `Error 'Duplicate entry '411465' for key 1' on query` means that the slave read and attempted to execute a binary log event to insert a row that already existed, ie. the same value `411465` for your primary key.

The most likely cause of this is the the insert was executed on the slave. To diagnose the query, you would use [mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html) and use the binary log coordinates from `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`. This will give you the server-id that the query originated from, which will match either your main master or 'passive' master.

Once you determine the query, you can identify the row on the server that is throwing the slave error to determine next steps. You can choose to :

- skip the entry using [`SET GLOBAL sql_slave_skip_counter=1`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-global-sql-slave-skip-counter.html) to proceed to the next binary log statement
- Delete the specific row on the server and start slave to have the statement run from replication.

However, you need to take steps to understand how the mismatch occurred, or you're going to run into this again. This will require some more detective work from your end using `mysqlbinlog`.

If, as you say, only one master is writeable at a time, you should ensure the following:

- passive master is `read_only=1` and your failover solution is able to modify read_only.
- the user that your application runs as (or any other non-trusted user) does not have the `SUPER` privilege. Any user with `SUPER` privilege can execute statements even on `read_only=1` servers.
- setup [pt-table-checksum](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-checksum.html) to ensure the data is in sync on both servers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will follow your advices.
By the way i find the source of my problem, when i duplicated my servers i duplicated cron tasks too, and this is why i've got records on my slave... I think if i fix this, and put the read only settings, my replication will be better.